# how to get more than five results in google map AutoComplete API

Tags: iphone, google-maps

I am using this API and getting only five results on place search as written in this API documentation.
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/autocomplete

is there any way to get more results. if yes please tell me thanks a lot.

Comment: Hi, did you find the solution for that?

Answer (score 7):

Per the article you linked: Predictions contains an array of places, with information about the place. See Place Autocomplete Results for information about these results. **The Places API returns up to 5 results.**

You will not be able to get more than 5 results.